# MapReduce arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mapreduce

I have two arrays like this:

```
["1","7","8","10"]
```

and

```
["1","2","3","6","9","11"]
```

These arrays represents ids from a class called `Place` that a user selected. I want to select the places ids with most votes. I tried `transpose` but as the arrays have different sizes, they cannot be transposed.

The expected output for this example is:

```
{ "1" => 2, "7" => 1, "8" => 1, "10" => 1, "2" => 1, "3" => 1, "6" => 1, "9" => 1, "11" => 1 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join all arrays and calculate the number of identical elements like this:

```
arrays = [["1","7","8","10"], ["1","2","3","6","9","11"]].reduce(:+)
arrays.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |memo, e| memo.update(e => memo[e] + 1) }
# "{ "1" => 2, "7" => 1, "8" => 1, "10" => 1, "2" => 1, "3" => 1, "6" => 1, "9" => 1, "11" => 1 }"
```

Once you have this intermediate result use `max_by` to select the key with the max value from the hash:

```
arrays = [["1","7","8","10"], ["1","2","3","6","9","11"]].reduce(:+)
arrays.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |memo, e| memo.update(e => memo[e] + 1) }
      .max_by { |_, count| count }[0]
#=> "1"
```

Comment: but I can (and will have) more arrays, and I will need th second most selected option. I need something like `{1=> 2, 7 => 1, 8 => 1}` and so on

Comment: Beginning with `array = [...] + [...]` is awkward because the number of arrays can vary. I suggest you regard `array` as an array of arrays, and then add the `array.reduce(:+)` extra step. Aside from that, good answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Yes, you are right. When he has more than two array, then `flatten` or `reduce` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way:

```
arr = [["1","7","8","10"], ["1","2","3","6","9","11"], ["1","2","7"]]

h = arr.flatten.sort_by(&:to_i).group_by(&:itself)
h.update(h) { |_,v| v.size }
  #=> {"1"=>3, "2"=>2, "3"=>1, "6"=>1, "7"=>2, "8"=>1, "9"=>1, "10"=>1, "11"=>1}
```

The steps:

```
a = arr.flatten
  #=> ["1", "7", "8", "10", "1", "2", "3", "6", "9", "11", "1", "2", "7"] 
b = a.sort_by(&:to_i)
  #=> ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "6", "7", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"] 
h = b.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"1"=>["1", "1", "1"], "2"=>["2", "2"], "3"=>["3"], "6"=>["6"],
  #    "7"=>["7", "7"], "8"=>["8"], "9"=>["9"], "10"=>["10"], "11"=>["11"]}
```

If you are using a version of Ruby prior to 2.2 (when [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was introduced) you will need to instead write:

```
h = b.group_by { |s| s }
```

Lastly:

```
h.update(h) { |_,v| v.size }
  #=> {"1"=>["1", "1", "1"], "2"=>["2", "2"], "3"=>["3"], "6"=>["6"],
  #    "7"=>["7", "7"], "8"=>["8"], "9"=>["9"], "10"=>["10"], "11"=>["11"]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block  (here `{ |_,v| v.size }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged (which in this case is all of the keys).

Update: the method [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. This allows us to write the following.

```
arr.flatten.
    sort_by(&:to_i).
    group_by(&:itself).
    transform_values(&:size)
```